# Can't use apt AT ALL for installing or removing ANY package - 'could not load /boot/System.map-4.8.0-59-generic: No such file or directory'

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel

NOTE: I doubt this question is a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962357/fatal-could-not-load-boot-system-map-4-8-0-54-generic-no-such-file-or-directo) because I don't use DKMS

---

Hello, on my server (recently restored from a horrific kernel issue), `apt autoremove --purge` gives this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 161 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 264820 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic (4.8.0-59.64) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.8.0-59-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-59-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-59-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-59-generic
cp: failed to restore the default file creation context: Invalid argument
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/kmod failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-59-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

A line of interest here is this:

```
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.8.0-59-generic: No such file or directory
```

`ls /boot`:

```
0 LD-Server /etc/update-motd.d ls /boot
abi-4.15.0-42-generic     grub/                         System.map-4.15.0-42-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic
config-4.15.0-42-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic  System.map-4.15.0-43-generic
config-4.15.0-43-generic  retpoline-4.15.0-42-generic   vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic
```

I see a `System.map-4.15.0-42-generic` and `System.map-4.15.0-43-generic` but no `System.map-4.8.0-59-generic`...

My server seems to boot fine (it is running now after all), but I don't exactly feel like testing it right now... Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Try running `sudo /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` and see if it generates a new autoremove script, then try the `sudo apt autoremove` again.

Comment: @Terrance Same error...

Comment: Try using `sudo touch /boot/System.map-4.8.0-59-generic` to create a dummy file for the package manager to remove. Then try the removal again.

Comment: In `terminal` do `dpkg -l *4.8.0-59* | grep -i ii` to see if the system thinks it's still installed. If it does, type `sudo apt-get purge {put package name here}`.

Comment: @user535733 The depmod warning is gone but it still fails with the same messages.

Comment: @heynnema `ic linux-image-4.8.0-59-generic [...] iH linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59.64-generic` Is this bad?

Comment: Time to use 'force': Try `sudo dpkg --purge --force linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic

Comment: @user535733 dpkg: error: unknown force/refuse option 'linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic'

Comment: Typo there, sorry. Try: `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic`

Comment: @user535733 https://pastebin.com/R28CXzLU

Comment: Do you happen to have the package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic in your /var/cache/apt/archives? If so, then reinstall the package so it will remove properly. If not, then it's time for the dangerous-and-rarely-used nuclear option; try `sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic`

Comment: It fails while running `update-initramfs`. It appears that `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/kmod` acts up. what is the output of `cat /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/kmod`?

Comment: I hope this help you https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1776652 #4

Comment: @user535733 the nuclear option doesn't work either, same output as that pastebin.

Comment: @kenn kmod hook is this: https://pastebin.com/Vm8GVJgV

Comment: @kenn Oh my god THANK YOU, commenting out that line then using the dpkg command user535733 gave me worked, make it an answer so I can accept it and give you bounty!! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `initramfs-tools` bug opened in this link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1776652

In this specific case it was triggered by faulty line in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/kmod`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Copy the compatibility symlinks until initramfs-tools will be converted
# to use the kmod program.

if [ "$1" = "prereqs" ]; then exit 0; fi

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

copy_exec /bin/kmod
cp -a /sbin/modprobe /sbin/rmmod $DESTDIR/sbin/

mkdir -p $DESTDIR/lib/modprobe.d/
if [ "$(echo /lib/modprobe.d/*)" != "/lib/modprobe.d/*" ]; then
  cp -a /lib/modprobe.d/* $DESTDIR/lib/modprobe.d/
fi
```

Commenting the line

```
 #cp -a /sbin/modprobe /sbin/rmmod $DESTDIR/sbin/
```

tricks `update-initramfs` command to bypass the error.